# override dns nameserver

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp

i wish to set higher priority for my dns nameservers, or override the ones that are being set by the dhcp server. no matter which approach i took, `nslookup` never displays the right dns nameserver.

please see the snippet below.

```
$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i dist
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

**resolvconf:**

```
$ cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base 
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
$ sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
$ sudo resolvconf -u
$ nslookup
> server
Default server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
```

**dhcp:**

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf 
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;
$ sudo service networking restart
$ nslookup
> server
Default server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
```

**how it can be done??**

Comment: The DNS server `nslookup` is using is the one in your system, which is then using (or should be using) 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220. See [this](http://www.leonardoborda.com/blog/127-0-1-1-ubuntu-debian/) about 127.0.1.1.

Comment: @saiarcot895, how do i verify that this is indeed the case? do i have to monitor the communication packets?

Comment: «`nslookup` never displays the right dns nameserver» It displays your own computer, which you configured to use OpenDNS... If this is not right, what would be the right one?

Comment: You could have simply added your dns to `supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;` in dhclient.conf

Comment: This question is different from the [flagged duplicated question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63160/how-to-override-the-dhcp-provided-nameserver).  The duplicate question doesn't have any answers that work for the OP of that question.  He checkmarked what he thought was the best answer, but commented at the same time that the answer doesn't work.  This OP's question is about the name server resolve.  He showed his attempt for using configuring his `/etc/resolvconf` package.  The answer provides the crutial step he mentioned.  His changes needs to be in `head`, not `base`.

Comment: The accepted answer in this question will work for DNS resolutions whether they are using DHCP or static configurations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a header to your resolvconf configuration file.  Create or edit the file, "***/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head***".  Add your preference to it.

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


nameserver 8.8.8.8
search [yourpreference.com]
```

Restart your networking service, rebooting is the surest way to restart it.

Comment: @MrRoth The comment in the `head` file does not apply to the file itself, but the composite `/etc/resolv.conf` that is generated by concatenating the fragments.

Answer (score 1):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/63163/267945 - much better solution:

> If you want to override or append to the name servers suggested by the
>   DHCP server, you can configure this in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, eg:
>
> ```
> interface "eth0" {
>     prepend domain-name-servers 10.0.0.2;
> }
> ```

Comment: This one worked for me on kubuntu. All the other things I've tried did not. Not sure I understand the network config (services/etc) of my computer - but as long as this works for now I'm good.