# Set enp0s3 as primary interface

Tags: networking, server

I've just installed the Ubuntu-Server-18.04.2 from via my virtual machine. I've added 2 network cards, the 1st adapter is a brigged adapter, the 2nd is configured as internal network with the ip: 172.168.16.1

The 1st network adapter receives the ip configuration from my router. So the problem is that I have no connection to the external network, because if I ping google for example, the ping is coming from my internal network adapter with the 172.... So I have no clue how to change it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1144788/edit) your question to include the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and any other network configuration files you've set? More specifically, how did you configure your internal network's NIC?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS issue.

Add a header to your resolvconf configuration file. Create or edit the file, "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head". Add your preference to it.

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


nameserver 8.8.8.8
search [yourpreference.com]
```

See [override dns nameserver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479506/override-dns-nameserver) for more information.

Comment: The resolv.conf is just in the etc directory. Do I need to create the folder resolvconf and move the .conf file into it?

Comment: You'll need to create it.

Comment: @Sam how do you figure this is a DNS issue?

Comment: I've disconnected the internal adapter and now I can communicate with the external network through my router. I would also claim that this is not a DNS issue, as I've tried your method but it hasn't worked.

Comment: If you try to ping Google, your DNS decides which adapter answers first. Setting your DNS manually to use one or the other will accomplish what you requested.

Comment: I haven't only tried it with DNS names, I've tried it also with just the IP-address of a server, but the internal adapter is still the source from the ping. That's why I think it's not about the DNS

Comment: If it doesn't work with the other adapter by itself then it could be that DNS is not working or another network layer level issue. NAT could be the cause as well. If you are using VirtualBox, you have to create an internal network and add port forwarding. Note that the internal network will have no access to the external, as that's how it works.